# Cannot add Product to Shopify Cart from external domain

Tags: shopify, cart

I am having trouble with adding a Product to my Shopify store's shopping cart from an external domain.  I have created a product which has a variant id of 264554714.  There are other variants, but I have reduced it to one and still cannot get it to work.  I have followed all examples in the Shopify forums and on Stackoverflow, but to no avail.  My form looks like what is stated to work.

```
<form id="submitProduct" action="http://mydomain.com/cart/add" method="post" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="264554714">
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

I have tried many different methods of submitting the form and/or variation combinations.  It feels like there is something simple missing.  I am hosting this Shopify app on Google App Engine, using Python and Django.  I have ensured that the Product exists with the exact variant ID.  Please let me know if there is something I haven't thought of to try.

Thank you.

Comment: There are no variants with the given ID, are you positive about the variant ID? Also, are you using your domain, or the address of your Shopify shop for the action url? It should be the URL for your shop.

Comment: The variant ID is the correct one.  I have confirmed that from the shop, and the domain is the address of the shop.  In either case, I have found another way to add the items to the cart via permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to this party. But if you want to post to the shopify shopping cart you only need to include the product variant ID in a permalink to your store as a key-value pair... it isn't a form submission, shopify will parse the custom URL and add the product to your cart automagically.

```
<a href="http://your-store.myshopify.com/cart/70881412:1,70881382:1">buy now</a>
```

Where 70881412 is the product variant's ID and 1 is the quantity.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger that, without actually navigating the user there? I've been trying to find a working solution for adding to cart without either refresh or redirect.

Comment: The way I've been going about it, is I've created my own shopping cart on my website, and have been storing all the unique variant IDs and quantities in local storage on my site. Then when I want to check out, I populate everything from local storage into a string variable and pass that into the custom URL. I attached the whole thing to a button marked "check out" so I'm only really using Shopify to process payments and send orders to my fulfillment company. Oh, the wonders of HTML5 and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to put in what I stated in my comment.  I was never able to get the post to store.com/cart/add to work using even a single variant ID, let alone multiple variant options.  I realized, though, that the permalinks provided by Shopify work just fine for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the Shopify tutorial on this subject: http://wiki.shopify.com/Adding_to_the_Cart_from_a_remote_website

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but that is the source I was following to attempt the form POST to the store.  It still wouldn't work for me.